# Problem to rotate Quaternion on two axes with reference to a plane in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have only been able to rotate it in the x axis but I would also like to do it in the z with the movement of the mouse. Sorry for the mistakes is google translator.

```
[SerializeField] private float camRotationAmount = 0.2f;
public Quaternion newRotation;


newRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, Time.deltaTime * camSmoothness);
```

I would like to add Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") for Vector3.left without tilting the camera. it's for a rts game. Thanks

Comment: in general you will want to separate the Y and X rotation hte following way: Rotate around Y in **global** space, rotate around X in **local** space. Whether you do this purely by logic or using a parent-child hierarchy is up to you ... second is easier to understand in my opinion

Comment: It is not possible to do it on the same object?

Comment: afaik not that trivial ... it is far easier to simply separate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you will want to **separate** the Y and X rotation the following way:

- rotate around Y in **global** space
- rotate around X in **local** space.

Whether you do this purely by logic or using a parent-child hierarchy is up to you ... second is easier to understand in my opinion.

---

#### Using the Hierarchy

There you would simply have a hierarchy like e.g.

```
CameraAnchor
|--Camera
```

and have a script on the `CameraAnchor` like e.g.

```
public class CameraAnchorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float cameraSmoothness = 5f;

    private Quaternion targetGlobalRotation;
    private Quaternion targetLocalRotation;

    private Transform child;

    private void Start()
    {
        child = transform.GetChild(0);

        targetGlobalRotation = transform.rotation;
        targetLocalRotation = transform.GetChild(0).localRotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        targetGlobalRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
        targetLocalRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        var lerpFactor = cameraSmoothness * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetGlobalRotation, lerpFactor);
        child.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(child.localRotation, targetLocalRotation, lerpFactor);
    }
}
```

---

#### Using Quaternion math

As said you could do the same thing in one single object but I would still keep both rotations separated:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float cameraSmoothness = 5f;

    private Quaternion targetGlobalRotation;
    private Quaternion targetLocalRotation = Quaternion.identity;

    private void Start()
    {
        targetGlobalRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        targetGlobalRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
        targetLocalRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetGlobalRotation * targetLocalRotation, cameraSmoothness * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Now why does this work when we are still using `Vector3.right` now?

By doing `targetGlobalRotation * targetLocalRotation` we first rotate around the global Y axis and then apply the rotation on the X axis based on this already applied rotation -> it is now an additional local rotation!

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I have the problem of roll on the camera https://ibb.co/WvSWzLH

Comment: oh should have been `targetLocalRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * ...`

Comment: The code was cut

Comment: @RexTool look at the update at the bottom. I think I now found the solution for a single object ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to work I appreciate the answers. it would only be change by Quaternion.identity

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I've been trying for hours without finding a good solution. I need to make a clamp between two angles for the X axis, for example minimum 10 degrees maximum 90 degrees, how would it be in that case?

Comment: @RexTool in that case you would rather clamp the euler angles before converting it to `Quaternion` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69655905/7111561))