# Clamp a quaternion rotation in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, clamp

I have this code but I have not been able to find a decent solution to clamp the X axis between 2 angle values. How would it be done in this case?

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {
    public float cameraSmoothness = 5f;

    private Quaternion targetGlobalRotation;
    private Quaternion targetLocalRotation = Quaternion.Identity;

    private void Start(){
        targetGlobalRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update(){
        targetGlobalRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(
            Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
        
        targetLocalRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(
            Vector3.right * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(
            transform.rotation,
            targetGlobalRotation * targetLocalRotation,
            cameraSmoothness * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I found a possible solution in case it works for someone: `code`if(transform.rotation.x * 180f > yAxisMin && Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") > 0 || transform.rotation.x * 180f < yAxisMax && Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") < 0){
                targetLocalRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
            }`code`

Comment: Where yAxisMin and yAxisMax are the minimum and maximum values ​​for y

Comment: But it still doesn't work 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you would rather use Euler angles and only convert them to `Quaternion` after applying the clamp!

**Never** directly touch individual components of a `Quaternion` unless you really know exactly what you are doing! A [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) has **four** components `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` and they all move in the range `-1` to `1` so what you tried makes little sense ;)

It could be something like e.g.

```
// Adjust via Inspector
public float minXRotation = 10;
public float maxXRotation = 90;

// Also adjust via Inspector
public Vector2 sensitivity = Vector2.one;

private float targetYRotation;
private float targetXRotation;

private void Update()
{
    targetYRotation += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")) * sensitivity.x;      
    targetXRotation -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")) * sensitivity.y;

    targetXRotation = Mathf.Clamp(targetXRotation, minXRotation, maxXRotation);

    var targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * targetYRotation) * Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * targetXRotation);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, cameraSmoothness * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again, I'm just starting out and the quaternions are tricky

Answer (score 1):

Clamp rotation on all axes, like limiting the Head-Rotation to avoid that "owl" move. Let's say the looking-target is behind you - you want to look over your shoulder, but not turn further. So we limit the angle relative to the transforms (forward) rotation.

```
Vector3 directionToTarget = transform.position - target.position;
Quaternion targetRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(directionToTarget);
Quaternion clampedTargetRot = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, lookRotation, 90f);
headTransform.rotation = clampedTargetRot;
```

Limiting to 90° means the head could go left or right, so the overall movement range is 180°.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to Clamp Mouse Y + transform.rotation.x like this

```
    _mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _horizontalSensitive;
    _camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, _mouseX, 0);

    _mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _verticalSensitive;
    _mouseY = Mathf.Clamp(_mouseY, -90, 90);
    _camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(_mouseY, 0, 0);
```

PS: _camera represent any gameobject on your scene

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).